# Repeatable task in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, task, runner

I am writing desktop app using Kotlin and I want to repeat execution of function for every X seconds.

I found solutions with using android library, there is other option? Maybe something like TaskRunner in Java?

**SOLUTION**

I used `Timer().schedule(startAfter, delay){...}` easy and simple ;)

Comment: `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Using thread pool and delay/sleep?

Comment: No, it's a scheduled executor service. Schedule the task with repetition.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can You write example? I want repeat one function every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [timer function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/timer.html) from kotlin-stdlib

Example of usage:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)  {
    val timer = timer(period = 1000) { // period in milliseconds
        println("this task is repeating 10 times")
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    timer.cancel()
    timer.purge()
}
```

Comment: I think the example is wrong. It sleeps 10s and then quits without printing

Comment: I have test it before posting the answer and It works

Comment: This is just a wrapper around Java 1.3 `Timer`, superseded by Java 5 `ScheduledExecutorService`. It's OK for basic usage, but each timer starts its own thread.

Comment: I'm agree to not overuse this method. But OP do not precise how many functions are schedules at various rates.

Comment: Thanks! But I found better solution, please check ;) (main post edited)